# Bubble Sort not Sorting and extra elements

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, scanf

I am trying to make a bubble sort in descending order and I keep getting a weird output. When I am inputting the elements in the array, for element 1 it asks me for element 1 more than once, and it causes an extra element to be taken in and another thing is that the final element is not included in the array at all, which I am not understanding. This is the output of my full program, and my code is under it:

Input:

```
How many elements in your array?: 4
Enter elements in your array: 
Element 0: 
97
32
Element 1: 
13
Element 2: 
22
Element 3: 
244
Element 0: 32
Element 1: 13
Element 2: 22
Element 3: 0
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int array[], int n);

int main() {

    int num = 0;
    printf("How many elements in your array?: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(num > 9)
        {
        printf("Only enter an array that is size 9 or less.\n");
        printf("Enter a new number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        }
    int array[num];
    printf("Enter elements in your array: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {   
        printf("Element %d: \n",i);
        scanf("%d ",&array[i]);
    }
    sort(array, num);
    for(int j = 0; j < num; j++)
    {
        printf("Element %d: %d\n", j, array[j] );

    }
    return 0;
}

void sort(int array[], int size)
{
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        /*if(array[i] > array[i+1]) // smallest to biggest
        {
            *temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;

        }*/
        if(array[i] > array[i+1]) // 1 2
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input. That's half of your problems.

Comment: What happens if you enter -1?

Comment: Your `sort` overflow the buffer, because when `i` is `size -1`, `array[i+1]` lies beyond the limit. So you are comparing with an undefined value which will affect the sorting. Also this is not bubble sort, you are just sorting adjacent entries, not the whole thing.

Comment: `scanf("%d ",&array[i]);` Remove the space after the `%d`. Then comment out the call to `sort`, and make sure that you at least started with a good array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments, your "*bubble sort*" will never sort, because it isn't a *bubble sort*. A bubble sort implementation for your variables would be similar to:

```
int i, j, swap;

for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {  /* For decreasing order use < */
            swap = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, your use of `scanf` is full of pitfalls. You **Must** validate the return of `scanf` to determine (1) Did the user cancel input by generating a manual `EOF` using <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze)?; (2) Was there an *input* or *matching* failure that resulted in no conversion taking place?; and (3) If the conversion succeeded, is the value within the acceptable range? In your case that would take the form of:

```
    int num = 0,
        rtn;
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
        printf ("\nHow many elements in your array?: ");
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &num);
        if (rtn == EOF) {
            fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {
            int c;
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            /* discard any characters that remain after input failure */
            for (c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
        }
        else if (num > 9) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: elements must be 9 or less.\n");
        }
        else
            break;
    }
```

(**note:** after an input failure, you must discard any characters that remain in `stdin`, otherwise, on the next iteration, your conversion will fail again leading to an infinite loop -- one of the primary pitfalls with using `scanf` for user input)

You can use an abbreviate check for the array values (rather than loop until you get correct input, you are just bailing, which eliminates discarding characters, etc.). However, there is no reason you cannot implement a fully robust solution in that loop, (implementing the full check and looping until all array elements are filled or the user cancels input).

```
    printf("\nEnter elements in your array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {   
        printf("Element[%2d]: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d",&array[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Putting all the pieces together, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *array, int size);

int main (void) {

    int num = 0,
        rtn;
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
        printf ("\nHow many elements in your array?: ");
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &num);
        if (rtn == EOF) {
            fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {
            int c;
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            for (c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
        }
        else if (num > 9) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: elements must be 9 or less.\n");
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    int array[num];     /* VLA for array */

    printf("\nEnter elements in your array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {   
        printf("Element[%2d]: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d",&array[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    sort (array, num);

    putchar ('\n');
    for(int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        printf("Element %d: %d\n", j, array[j]);

    return 0;
}

void sort(int *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {  /* For decreasing order use < */
                int swap = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bubblesort_input

How many elements in your array?: twenty
error: invalid input.

How many elements in your array?: 12
error: elements must be 9 or less.

How many elements in your array?: 6

Enter elements in your array:
Element[ 0]: 12
Element[ 1]: 2
Element[ 2]: -12
Element[ 3]: -4
Element[ 4]: 5
Element[ 5]: 1

Element 0: -12
Element 1: -4
Element 2: 1
Element 3: 2
Element 4: 5
Element 5: 12
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to mention other problems also? But yes...right implementation.

Comment: Thank You, this help tremendously! It cleared up alot of my misunderstandings.

Comment: Glad it helped. Learning to use `scanf` correctly is largely a character accounting problem and knowing which *conversions* (the numeric ones) consume leading whitespace and which don't so you know what is leftover in `stdin` after it completes successfully (and after a failure). That's a big part of why `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`) -- the *line oriented* input functions, are the preferred ways to take user input -- but `scanf` does have its valid uses for *formatted* input, just as `getchar` does for *character oriented* input.